# Как записать ошибку для отправки на сервер если приложение крашится?

Tags: java, android

На сервер отправляю ошибки в асинтаске, но если приложение вылетает, то как в таком случае ловить и отправлять ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно для отлова ошибок воспользоваться специальными крэш-репортерами, наподобие [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/).

Comment: Да действительно интересная штука) Спасибо! Только вот не пойму один момент, можете подсказать. Вот эта строка `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` мне ее нужно продублировать на каждом активити или только на `Main` как в примере?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - это интегрировать Google Analytics. Он, кроме аналитики, так же и собирает все краши.